# UWP - binding Enum differences

Tags: c#, enums, windows-runtime, uwp, winmd

I have come across a very interesting issue.

Suppose you have the following XAML page content in a UWP app:

```xml
<ContentControl Content="{x:Bind ApplicationDataLocalityEnum}" />
<ContentControl Content="{x:Bind FontStyleEnum}" />
```

And in the code-behind of the page contains the following properties:

```cs
    public ApplicationDataLocality ApplicationDataLocalityEnum { get; } =
               ApplicationDataLocality.Local;

    public FontStyle FontStyleEnum { get; } = 
               FontStyle.Normal;
```

**Expected** result would be, that the app would display "Local" and "Normal".

**Actual** result is however the following:

[image]

What is the reason behind this? I am very curious about it, but even though I have tried digging into debugger values for a long time, it never revealed anything that could cause this.

You can play around with my [sample project on GitHub](https://github.com/MartinZikmund/Stack-Overflow-2016/tree/master/EnumDisplayQuestion).

Comment: While I can't answer your actual question, if it's causing you a problem and you need a work around then best create a value converter so you can get it to display correctly. Will be very interested to see the real answer though!

Comment: Yes, I know ValueConverter works, but I am asking out of curiosity, because I am really unable to figure this out :-D .

Comment: I've just been playing around with this and so far i can see it's only happening within a ContentControl. When using a standard TextBlock/TextBox the selected FontStyle is displayed correctly. It may be something to do with the way a ContentControl renders its content, possibly a bug.

Comment: But if you try to use a ListView with a ItemTemplate and put a TexBlock inside of it and bind the Text property there - it happens again! I just have bo idea how this can be :-D

Comment: Also - if you use type FontStyles and a dot (to get IntelliSense in Visual Studio), you will see that it offers much more methods than other enums, again for unknown reasons.

Comment: Please don't use a ValueConverter for something like this. Just create `public string FontStyleString => FontStyleEnum.ToString();` in your code-behind class.

Comment: That is the best solution, but I am still struggling to understand why this happens when `ToString()` behaves as expected :-) .

Answer (score 3):

Should you look into the source of `FontStyle` (just hit F12) you will find it is in `Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd`. This is not a .NET assembly, but a native assembly projected into .NET. MSDN for [IReference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br225864.aspx) says:

> When programming with .NET, this interface is hidden and developers should use the Nullable class. All Windows Runtime members where the basic IDL signature shows IReference (with a constraint) are instead exposed using the nullable syntax of the nullable value type (for example, ?bool).

#### So why doesn't it work?

The heart of the answer is, this is not a .NET type and does not behave like a .NET type. Meaning `ToString()` is not natively implemented as if it is an `enum` but acts instead like `GetType().ToString()`, which explains the output you are seeing.

#### Why don't they make it work?

To correct this on the platform side, the type would need a mechanism to differentiate between numerations, structures and delegates. In the case of structures and delegates, you would expect `ToString()` to return `GetType().ToString()` and not a name value; so this generic behavior is the most common choice across the options.

Comment: But what makes `FontStyle` different from `ApplicationDataLocality` for example, which according to F12 is also in `Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd`?