# UWP ComboBox: ItemsSource population through enum

Tags: c#, combobox, enums, uwp

so I want to populate a combobox items source with the contents on an enum (and obviously retrieve the values later on).

Populating works fine with either of the two following approaches but neither matches what I want to achieve.

```
comboBox.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(VirtualKey));
```

I can retrieve the values without issue using a simple (VirtualKey)comboBox.SelectedItem. The problem is, the names in the dropdown menu are all unreadable.
[image]

```
comboBox.ItemsSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(VirtualKey));
```

Displays the names as intended but I can't retrieve the value like with the other instruction.

Any ideas how to solve the situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `comboBox.ItemsSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(VirtualKey));`
>
> Displays the names as intended but I can't retrieve the value like with the other instruction.

I don't know how are you getting the selected value, but for converting from enum value name to its value, you can use the [`Enum.Parse(Type, String)` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559(v=vs.110).aspx).

Or you can bind the `ComboBox.SelectedIndex` to your enum variable for example using something like my [`EnumToIntConverter`](https://github.com/bramborman/UWPHelper/blob/master/UWPHelper/UWPHelper/Converters/EnumToIntConverter.cs).

Comment: Thank you very much! Enum.Parse method works perfectly fine :)

Answer (score 1):

This puzzling behavior was also discussed here:

[UWP - binding Enum differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39299427/uwp-binding-enum-differences)

Even simple `ToString()` call overcomes this issue. For some reason however, some Windows Runtime enums in direct XAML binding show up with `IReference`.